# Python remove from list the same values

Tags: python, arrays, function

Please help.
I have in input script the differing values and what need only remove the same values.

I do this but there is didn't check the type of value and only just didn't find it.

Example :

```
import sys
def clean_list(list_to_clean):
        c = []
        c = list(set(list_to_clean))
        return c
c= clean_list(sys.argv[1:])
print c
```

or

```
import sys
def clean_list(list_to_clean):
        c = []
        for i in list_to_clean:
                if i not in c:
                        c.append(i)
        return c
c= clean_list(sys.argv[1:])
print c
```

so my problem, when i in input send values :

> 'asd', 'dsa', 1, '1', 1.0

it was back :

> ['asd', 'dsa', 1, '1']

but need :

> ['asd', 'dsa', 1, '1', 1.0]

Thanks

Comment: You will need to add explicit checks if that's the behaviour you want - `1.0 in (1,)` evaluates truth-y, although `1.0 is 1` doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Since int 1 and float 1.0 hash to the same value, you need to retain some more information about the object -- it's 'type' is the best candidate here.  You can do this in a one liner if you want:

```
>>> seq = ['asd', 'dsa', 1, '1', 1.0, 'asd', 'dsa', 1]
>>> [pair[1] for pair in {(type(obj), obj,) for obj in seq}]
['asd', 'dsa', 1, 1.0, '1']
```

Breaking it down a bit more, the set comprehension:

```
pairs = {(type(obj), obj,) for obj in seq}
```

Retains the type of obj in a tuple so it's not lost.  Then the list comprehension just gets back the value (not the type):

```
final_answer = [pair[1] for pair in pairs]
```

As an aside, you can use the builtin `hash` function to see what value python will use for dictionary/set hashing:

```
>>> hash(1.0)
1
>>> hash(1)
1
```

This is spelled out in the docs -- in fact, they mention the very case of 1 and 1.0.

- Python 2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash
- Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#hash

Answer (score 0):

Python automatically shortens the integer and, when the cleaning code sees it, it thinks it is a duplicate. Try storing it as a string `'1.0'` and then converting it back to an integer for usage using the `int` function.